# Viewing Pytest output with Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, pytest

I have a Pytest script I'd like to run on my flask models using Docker. I run my docker instance with

```
docker-compose up
```

I then attach to the instance

```
docker attach my-app-name-here
```

And then I run my tests

```
docker exec -it $APP_ID python tests.py
```

There are a bunch of assert statements in my test file but I can't get any output to the attached container. How can I see my test output in my local terminal/command-line?

Thank you

My test code (part of it for example)

```
def test_scores_model():
    scores = Scores(1, "7b25a87c-d2c8-49e3-83ac-88dcc1d94902", 4.5, 5.5, 3.5, 2.5, 4.5, 3.5, 0.5, 2.5, 3.5, 1.5, None)
    assert scores.scores_id == 1
    assert scores.session_id == "7b25a87c-d2c8-49e3-83ac-88dcc1d94902"
    assert scores.security == 4.5
```

Comment: How are you logging the docker output, if at all?

Comment: Does https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging help?

Comment: Nothing comes out in the logs except the spinning up stuff that occurs when I run docker-compose up @jtlz2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to run the command

```
docker exec -it $APP_ID pytest tests.py
```

Note that python has been replaced with pytest.